# DIV get 2 line when screen less 991px

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My bootstrap 2 `div's` in same line. But when screen less 991px Its comes 2 row. how to avoid this using CSS.

```
<div class="myclass">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-md-3" style="background-color: #1b6d85">1 assdasddasd</div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-md-9" style="background-color: #66512c">2 asas</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's the principle of Bootstrap, to be responsive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change class name

```
<div class="myclass row">
    <div class="col-xs-3" style="background-color: #1b6d85">1 assdasddasd</div>
    <div class="col-xs-9" style="background-color: #66512c">2 asas</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row myclass">
        <div class="col-xs-3" style="background-color: #1b6d85">1 assdasddasd</div>
        <div class="col-xs-9" style="background-color: #66512c">2 asas</div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style="background-color: #1b6d85">1 assdasddasd</div>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9" style="background-color: #66512c">2 asas</div>
</div>
```

row is for wrap to single line

Comment: There's no need to define the column classes for 3 different screen sizes, if you only use one layout. Also, if you use different layouts for the available screen sizes, you should start with the smallest available screen size (e.g. XS). This is the mobile first principle. 

More information on mobile first can be found here: https://codemyviews.com/blog/mobilefirst

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="myclass">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3" style="background-color: #1b6d85">1 assdasddasd</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-9 col-md-9" style="background-color: #66512c">2 asas</div>
    </div>
```